# sql same name but different value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can you retrieve all the lines that have the same name, but they have different values? For example, I have this table:

```
Name|Value|Description
Rob |Val1 |Text1
Alex|Val1 |Text2
Alan|Val2 |Text3
Alex|Val2 |Text4
Alex|Val2 |Text5  
Alan|Val2 |Text6
```

I want the query to return just the persons that appear more than once, but have different values. So the results would be:

```
Alex|Val1 |Text2 
Alex|Val2 |Text4 
Alex|Val2 |Text5
```

**Edit:** I added another row to the initial table. Some of the quesries will return Alan as part of the result too. I don't want that, since clearly it has the same value. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What's your SQL flavor ?

Comment: You edited the table. So also edit the desired output. :)

Comment: No, the result is good. I don't want it to return any info for Alan, because it has the same value. I want all the persons that have the same name, but don't have the same value.

Comment: @RoxanaDinca So you don't want to filter by `Description`. Correct?

Comment: @hims056 no, I am not interested in filtering by description.

Comment: @RoxanaDinca What's the problem with [the updated answer by Parado](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067483/1369235)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun ... 
A cross join might work something like (i haven't tested it) :

```
select distinct 
    p1.*
from 

    Persons p1 
cross join 
    Persons p2 
where 
        p1.Name = p2.Name 
    and p1.Value <> p2.value
    and p1.Description <> p2.Description
```

Now you can start a discussion on how efficient this would be ...
(But I won't be part of it ...)

Comment: The query does not work for any cases. If (Name+Value+Description) is not a factual primary key in the table, then the query may return duplicates results as well as simplified results. This is because the query assumes that (Name+Value+Description) is a unique combination that identify each record.

Comment: @Skrol29 Could you provide an example ? what line would you insert in original table to make it not working ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, in your example what is the missing line ?

Comment: You can see that 4 records "Alex" are inserted, only 3 are given by the query.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `join` and `sybquery` with `having`:

```
  select p.Name,p.Value,p.Description
    from persons P
    join ( select Name,Value
           from persons
            group by Name,Value
            having count(1)>1
          ) c on p.Name = c.Name
              and p.Value = c.Value
    order by p.Name;
```

or the same `subquery` in `exists` clause:

```
select p.Name,p.Value,p.Description
from persons P
where exists
     ( select Name,Value
       from persons c
        where p.Name = c.Name
        group by Name,Value
        having count(1)>1
      ) 
order by p.Name
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42c97/5/0) Demo

Solution for updated problem

```
select * 
from Persons c
where name in 
(
select  Name   from(
       select Name,Value 
       from persons        
        group by Name,Value) T

group by Name
  having count(1)>1
)
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f64d/36/0) Demo

Comment: Your first query with `group by Name,Value` will return a wrong result. It will duplicates each line by the number of duplicates (names+value).

Comment: @Skrol29 Did you see sql fiddle? For me there is no duplicates. It was solution for first problem.

Comment: Your first SQL Fiddle do returns the Alan record, which is an error. And this other SQL Fiddle shows the duplicate bug in your SQL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bba4c/1/0

Comment: @Skrol29 In example there isn't row `('Alex','Val1','Text7');`. Without this it works correctly for first problem.

Comment: The problem is not to found an arbitrary query returning the same result as the giving example. It also should solve the expressed problem for any example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple working solution:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Value, t.Description
FROM t_table AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM (
       SELECT Name FROM  t_table GROUP BY Name,Value
    ) AS sub1
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) AS sub2 ON (t.Name=sub2.Name)
ORDER BY t.Name, t.Value
```

Comment: Your query returns `Alex` and `Alan`, but she said _I don't want it to return any info for Alan_

Comment: Yes it works but only with `('Alex','Val1','Text7')` (or more), but without the row (rows only from example) it doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

> SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS A WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN 
>       (
>          SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 AS B WHERE B.NAME = A.NAME
>       ) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END